# tcl carriage return and html forms

Tags: html, split, tcl

I am capturing form data from a html form using textarea in to a variable.

I have three of these. Code Swap & Morph

```
<form action="/::storyBuild/&Create" method="POST">
<textarea name="code" title="" cols="19" rows="12"></textarea>
<textarea name="swap" title="" cols="19" rows="12"></textarea>
<textarea name="morph" title="" cols="19" rows="12"></textarea>
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Generate">
</form>
```

Within the site you enter a script

```
Code  Swap     Morph
kCode %animal1 Woof! I am a dog
kCode %animal2 Meow! I am a cat
kCode %animal3 Squeak I am a mouse
```

I have it capturing the data perfectly fine as expected, however I am failing to get it to split text area.

For example, if I use the following script

```
kCode %animal1 the dog is very wet from the rain
kCode $animal2 the cat is very cold from the snow
kCode %animal3 the mouse is very warm from the fire
```

Using the code

```
### display form data
set i 0

foreach formPost $formDataCode {

set code [lindex $formDataCode $i]
set swap [lindex $formDataSwap $i]
set morph [lindex $formDataMorph $i]

storyWrite "$myPath" "$code" "$swap" "$morph"
incr i
}

proc storyWrite {path code swap morph} {
set myPath "/some/path/"
set fp [open "$myPath" a]
puts $fp "$code $swap $morph"
close $fp
}
```

I discovered that while this was working for code and swap field, because these are single words, it was only capturing the first few words of the morph field. The morph variable holds the whole content

```
puts "My formData output: $formDataMorph"

My formData output: the dog is very wet from the rain
the cat is very cold from the snow
the mouse is very warm from the fire
```

llindex would only loop three times because the code variable has single three entries, each outputting both code and swap correctly it would only place the third word of morph when I would like it to be the third line.

The overall output I would get is:

```
the :: dog :: is :: %animal4
```

rather than

```
the dog is very wet from the rain :: the cat is very cold from the snow :: the mouse is very warm from the fire :: %animal4
```

I've tried implementing conditions using if statements both of which don't seem to work.

```
if { $formDataMorph eq "\r" } { puts "I found a carriage return" }
if { $formDataMorph eq "\n" } { puts "I found a newline" }
```

How would I go about doing this? How can I separate the additional lines from the variable?

Do I need to add a line delimiter check when inputting the script?

Thanks,
mookie

Comment: I don't really understand what's going on there. Try using `[lindex [split $formDataMorph \n] $i]` in your `foreach` loop instead of `[lindex $formDataMorph $i]`? Also, if you are using an iterator for a loop, it's better if you used `for` instead of `foreach`. Makes it easier for yourself.

Comment: Thank you, that worked. I'll look in to using a forloop.

Comment: Consider self-answering the question. Besides: What is the HTTP/ template-processing backend you are using? Where does the template syntax `%animal1` etc. coming from? As Jerry said, no one really understands what's going in your example.

Comment: Naviserver as the backend. There is no template processing fronted per-se. The syntax %animal1 is my own prototype. I am essentially encoding contents of a whole .html file to hexadecimal, assigning the string to a variable then preforming a replacement of certain hex values within the string. "find %animal1 (in hexadecimal) - replace with a word in hex" - decode the final hex string back to base16 and output on screen. Resulted in a fully rendered html page with all tags replaced with insanely speedy render.  kCodes / pCode are triggers whether to replace with a base64 img or text

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what the value in `formData` really is and how it got there, it's hard to be sure what's going wrong. However, it looks like the initial fix is to do:

```
foreach formPost ????? { # <<-- What you wrote looked wrong...
    set morph [join [lassign $formPost code swap]]
    storyWrite "$myPath" $code $swap $morph
}
```

For example, if the input data is in lines, we'd do:

```
foreach formPost [split $inputData "\n"] {
    set morph [join [lassign $formPost code swap]]
    storyWrite "$myPath" $code $swap $morph
}
```

But properly it's still wrong since it's still mixing up strings and lists. If the data was encoded *correctly* you'd instead do:

```
foreach formPost $inputData {
    storyWrite "$myPath" {*}$formPost
}
```

Otherwise, the safe string-to-list conversion is with:

```
foreach line [split $inputData "\n"] {
    set dataList [regexp -all -inline {\S+} $line]
    set morph [join [lassign $dataList code swap]]
    storyWrite "$myPath" $code $swap $morph
}
```

(I still worry about the handling of the input data in the first place; e.g., how can we be sure that there aren't spacs in the `code` or `swap` fields…?)

Comment: "how can we be sure that there aren't spacs in the code or swap fields…?" You can't but, it doesn't work if there is. The saved file is only read when rendering the webpage. It has to be entered correctly otherwise the rendered data would appear broken. the foreach loop is just something i've picked up that just works /shrug